# How can I make a modulus operator add odd numbers between two numbers in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, operator-keyword, modulus

Below is what I have so far. And do I place the user prompt within the function or leave it where it is? What I am "trying" to accomplish is to add

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html lang="en-us">
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script type="text/javascript">
/* Input: user types in an integer
 * Processing: adds all odd numbers between input and 0
 * Output: the sum of the odd numbers 
 */
 function addOdds() {
    var n = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value);  
        var sum = i=i+2;
            for **(var i = -1; i < 6; i = i + 2)** {
                if (n == 0) {
                    break;
                }
                sum += n;
            }
            window.alert(sum);
        }   
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    Please enter a number. <input type="text" id="number">
    <button type="button" onclick="addOdds()"> Get the sum </button>
    <div id=""> </div> <!--is this part need? -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should make the question complete within the post and not rely on the title or subject for detail. Simply test `if (n%2)`, it will evaluate to *true* if *n* is odd.

Comment: `var isOdd = (n % 2 == 1);`

Comment: You don't mean "odd numbers", apparently; you mean "numbers in odd positions".

Comment: @Jasen— `var isOdd = !!(n%2)`. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 1; i<=n; i+=2) {
   sum+=i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your function you have:

```
function addOdds() {
  var n = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value);  
  var sum = i=i+2;
```

*i* is declared below so its value is *undefined*. Adding 2 returns *NaN*. Just initialise *sum* to 0:

```
  var sum = 0;

  for (var i = -1; i < 6; i = i + 2) {
```

I think you need to start from 0, though it's even so start from 1. And you want to go up to *value*, so:

```
  for (var i=1; i<=n; i++) {
```

Now just add *i* if it's not even:

```
    sum += i%2? i : 0;
  }
```

and you're done.

```
  document.getElementById('sum').textContent = sum
}
```

Assuming that you also have:

```
<div id="sum"></div>
```

But I like Wee You's answer. ;-)

Comment: It seems he wants not to add odd numbers but rather to add numbers at odd locations in the array.

Comment: "LaurenB" is an unusual name for a "he". ;-) Not sure I know what the OP wants, apparently not this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it will help you..

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html lang="en-us">
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script type="text/javascript">
/* Input: user types in an integer
 * Processing: adds all odd numbers between input and 0
 * Output: the sum of the odd numbers 
 */
 function addOdds() {
    var n = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value);  
        var sum = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                if (i % 2 != 0) {
                    sum += i;
                }
                ;
            }
            window.alert(sum);
        }   
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    Please enter a number. <input type="text" id="number">
    <button type="button" onclick="addOdds()"> Get the sum </button>
    <div id=""> </div> <!--is this part need? -->
</body>
</html>
```